# Failed to install Phoenix Framework npm dependencies (phoenix & phoenix_html) with Travis CI

Tags: javascript, travis-ci, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix Framework project and I was testing with Travis CI. It worked smoothly with only elixir tests.

Today I was trying to add some JavaScript tests but then I found I could not resolve `phoenix` and `phoenix_html` since they are linked to local Phoenix dependencies in `pakcage.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "ava": "^0.18.2",
  ...
  "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
  "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html",
  "react": "^15.4.2"
  ...
},
```

So then it crashed on travis because of premission issue:

```
...
The command "mix test" exited with 0.
1.37s$ npm install
-\npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix Cloning into bare repository '/home/travis/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-file-deps-phoenix-c83d6c1a'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix and the repository exists.
\npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html Cloning into bare repository '/home/travis/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-file-deps-phoenix-html-50a27b71'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm mERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html and the repository exists.
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: react-hot-loader@'>=4.0.0-0 <5.0.0-0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.1.0","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4","0.1.5","0.1.6","0.1.7","0.1.8","0.1.9","0.1.10","0.1.11","0.2.0","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.4.2","0.4.3","0.4.4","0.4.5","0.5.0","1.0.0-alpha","1.0.0-alpha.1","1.0.0-alpha.2","1.0.0-alpha.3","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.1.4","1.1.5","1.1.6","1.1.7","1.2.0","1.2.1","1.2.2","1.2.3","1.2.4","1.2.5","1.2.6","1.2.7","1.2.8","1.2.9","2.0.0-alpha","2.0.0-alpha-1","2.0.0-alpha-2","2.0.0-alpha-3","1.3.0","2.0.0-alpha-4","3.0.0-alpha.0","3.0.0-alpha.1","3.0.0-alpha.2","3.0.0-alpha.3","3.0.0-alpha.4","3.0.0-alpha.5","3.0.0-alpha.6","3.0.0-alpha.7","3.0.0-alpha.8","3.0.0-alpha.9","3.0.0-alpha.10","3.0.0-alpha.11","3.0.0-alpha.12","3.0.0-alpha.13","3.0.0-beta.0","3.0.0-beta.1","3.0.0-beta.2","3.0.0-beta.3","3.0.0-beta.4","3.0.0-beta.5","3.0.0-beta.6","1.3.1"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! System Linux 4.8.12-040812-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/travis/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/node" "/home/travis/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/travis/build/namelos/namelos-elixir
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/travis/build/namelos/namelos-elixir/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
The command "npm install" exited with 1.
...
```

Here is my .travis.yml:

```
language: elixir
node_js:
  - 7.6.0
elixir:
  - 1.4.1
otp_release:
  - 19.0
sudo: false
addons:
  postgresql: '9.4'
install:
  - npm install
before_script:
  - mix do ecto.create, ecto.migrate
script:
  - mix test
  - npm test
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I figured it out. the 'node_js' was not working when the languages is not node, so the node version was just v0.10.36 as error log indicates.

And local dependencies are not working with that old version of node. So it failed.

Then I have to install specific version of node with nvm, as well as some elixir scripts because I overwrote some hooks, as following:

```
language: elixir
elixir:
  - 1.4.1
otp_release:
  - 19.0
sudo: false
addons:
  postgresql: '9.4'
env:
  - NODE_VERSION="7.7.2"
before_install:
  - mix local.rebar --force
  - mix local.hex --force
  - nvm install $NODE_VERSION
install:
  - mix deps.get
  - yarn install
before_script:
  - mix do ecto.create, ecto.migrate
script:
  - mix test
  - yarn test
```

But is there any way to make this shorter by declar elixir and node.js environment at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Your git clone fails.

Set your git config to

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/
```

instead Of git://github.com/